# Can I Run All The JavaScript Features on Dart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm a JavaScript Developer and I am Completely New To Mobile Development, i am using flutter by the way. So i Wanted to know If I can Use Dart Exactly Like JavaScript, Like Running JavaScript libraries or ejs view engine, etc..
Thanks.

Comment: please provide more information for example what specific features you want an alternative to? ALl programming languages and environments are different and its not a fair comparison to find one to one mapping and will become an open ended and opinionated answer.

Comment: You can't use Dart exactly like you use Javascript because Dart is a completely different programming language and requires its own syntax and usage rules.  You can compile Dart code to Javascript so that compiled code can be run in some Javascript environments.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Flutter @abdo-berro.

To find out the differences and similarities between JS and Flutter, you may check the article below:

https://blog.codemagic.io/dart-vs-javascript/

But generally, Flutter is a high-level language that is translated to native codes and compiled, seamlessly and silently. There are tons of packages helping developers to build state-of-the-art UIs, while using Dart to build app engine run fast and smooth.